# Xamarin Android App Respond to 'Share To' Request

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have developed an Android app, works really well, got my deep linking and open from file system working as expected. However, this afternoon I discovered something quirky, and I need your help.

If I click on a link from my website, the app can be used to open it, works as expected. If I go into the gallery on my phone and 'open' a picture, I can choose my app to receive it, this also works correctly. But today I noticed that Google Photos doesn't allow me to do that, it requires that I 'Share' the image, which is where my very minor issue comes in.

How do I setup my app to be able to receive an image from Google Photos? What should the intent filter be?

Comment: Do you want to get  a picture from Google Photo in your App? By `it requires that I 'Share' the image`, is it a error?

Comment: Yeah, if I save the image from Google photos (where you can't open, you have download or share), in the gallery app it just has share, whereas local images have the option to 'open with' which is what my app is setup to handle. But it doesn't come up in the share dialog, which is useless.

Comment: I can share to my app, the app opens, but there is no intent there to get the image so I can manipulate it. I need to know what the intent should look like

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this, but if your app is opening, can you not set a breakpoint and see what data is being passed in via the intent? Or maybe write some temporary code to spit that information out? That might help you to figure out how to pull the image data.

Comment: The problem is, my app doesn't show in the 'share to' list, but as my app shows in the open with list, I am assuming that I don't have right listening intent setup. That's why I am asking what the Intent should be to listen for, and receive shared files. Once the app opens I've got the code to grab the data I want. Just can't get it to respond to the request.
I really don't want to make a blank android app and create every single listening intent that it might be, and breakpoint each one !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register your app for share intent. Once done the OS will list your app in the list when you click the share icon

Add the below to your activity in which you want to receive the image

```
[IntentFilter(new[]{Intent.ActionSend},Categories = new[]{Intent.CategoryDefault},DataMimeType = "image/*",Label = "Your application name")]
```

eg:

```
[Activity(Label = "Your activity name"]
[IntentFilter(new[]{Intent.ActionSend}, Categories = new[]{Intent.CategoryDefault}, DataMimeType = "image/*",Label = "activity label")]
public class YourActivity: Activity
{
```

In OnCreate method check the intent :

```
if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend)
{
    if(Intent.Extras.ContainsKey(Intent.ExtraStream)){
            Uri fileUrl =(Android.Net.Uri)Intent.Extras.GetParcelable(Intent.ExtraStream));
        }
}
```

From the Uri you can access the image in file system.

Comment: ActionSend, that makes sense. Thanks